# How do you retrieve WebGL bitmap data?

Tags: canvas, webgl

It is possible to retrieve the bitmap data HTML Canvas 2D element, is it also possible to access the rendered content of a Canvas 3D / WebGL element as bitmap data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of WebGL's readPixels has changed in a later draft.

Instead of returning a new array with the pixel data everytime, you pass an array to fill as last argument :

void readPixels(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, ArrayBufferView pixels)

This allows to reuse the same array for multiple readPixels operations.

Answer (score 2):

Not as direct as using readPixels, but this might also work. You can also render the canvas to a Image element, like so:

```
var img = document.getElementById("game-canvas").toDataURL("image/jpeg");
$("#shots").append("<img src=\"" + img + "\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\"/>");
```

You have to get your webgl context with the special option preserveDrawingContext for this to work though:

```
var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```

From there on, if you want to manipulate the image easily, you could render that in a 2d canvas and read the pixels there if you want.

I regularly use this to take "screenshots" of the things I'm playing with.

Answer (score 1):

From the working draft of the [WebGL Specification](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/registry/trunk/public/webgl/doc/spec/WebGL-spec.html):

```
ArrayBufferView readPixels(GLint x, GLint y, 
    GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type)
```

> Return a ArrayBufferView with pixels
>   within the passed rectangle. The data
>   returned from readPixels must be
>   up-to-date as of the most recently
>   sent drawing command. Any unprocessed
>   drawing commands must be completed and
>   their results presented to the current
>   drawing buffers before readPixels
>   accesses the drawing buffer.
>
> The specific subclass of
>   ArrayBufferView returned depends on
>   the passed type. If it is
>   UNSIGNED_BYTE, a Uint8Array is
>   returned, otherwise a Uint16Array is
>   returned.